# JQ - non-recursive merge of top-level keys and values only

Tags: json, jq

Lots of JQ questions on here, but none of them seem to address what I'm looking for. I would like to take two JSON objects and merge them non-recursively.

```
{
    "a": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    }
}
```

merged into

```
{
    "a": {
        "3": "3"
    },
    "b": {
        "1": "1"
    }
}
```

should result in

```
{
    "a": {
        // Note "3" is not present, object "a" is completely replaced.
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    },
    "b": {
        "1": "1"
    }
}
```

Thanks! Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed `--slurp` combined with a simple `add`.

```
erin@laptop:~/tmp$ cat a.json 
{
    "a": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    }
}

erin@laptop:~/tmp$ cat b.json 
{
    "a": {
        "3": "3"
    },
    "b": {
        "1": "1"
    }
}

erin@laptop:~/tmp$ jq -s 'add' b.json a.json
{
  "a": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  },
  "b": {
    "1": "1"
  }
}
erin@laptop:~/tmp$
```